# Read existing data from DOM into model, ng-model for static data?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm currently playing around with rewriting the functionality of an existing page using Angular. The gist of it is that I have a plain HTML page with a list of stuff, like this:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item">
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <ul class="categories">
      <li class="category">Bar</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

This is augmented by some Javascript which parses this data once and adds a dynamic category filter menu to the page. I.e. it extracts all `li.category` elements and displays a menu with them, and clicking on one of these categories filters the item list to display only items with the chosen category.

I've replicated the basics of that in Angular with a lot less code than I had before. However, I'm still doing a lot of jQuery traversing of the `.item` elements to build that initial list of categories:

```js
myApp.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.categories = [];

    angular.element('.item').each(function () {
        angular.element(this).find('.categories .category').each(function () {
            var category = this.textContent;
            for (var i = 0, length = $scope.categories.length; i < length; i++) {
                if ($scope.categories[i].name == category) {
                    $scope.categories[i].count++;
                    $scope.categories[i].items.push(this);
                    return;
                }
            }
            $scope.categories.push({ name : category, count : 1, items : [this] });
        });
    });
});
```

This does not seem to be in the spirit of Angular, and I'd like to replace it with something like:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="item" ng-item>
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <ul class="categories">
      <li class="category" ng-category>Bar</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ...
</ul>
```

A directive should then be able to parse all `ng-item`/`ng-category` elements and add them to the model/scope once. Something like `ng-model`, but for static data.

I have virtually no experience with Angular, how can I accomplish this; or shouldn't I want to do something entirely different in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

For creating your own `ng-item` and `ng-category` directives, I suggest that you can go through `Creating Custom Directives` part in Angular Offical Develop Guide:

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

It will tell you how to begin creating your directive from add directive to module like this:

```
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
    return {
      template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
    };
});
```

### Edit:

This two is also useful tutorial:

1. http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html
2. http://www.befundoo.com/university/tutorials/angularjs-directives-tutorial/

### Edit2:

To answer your comment:

```
Do you have a concrete sample of how I'd write a directive that reads data from its element and modifies the controller's scope?
```

I thought that it has clear explanation in Angular Official Guide:

```
  .directive('myCustomer', function() {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              customerInfo: '=info'
          },
          templateUrl: 'my-customer-iso.html'
      };
  });
```

In this example:

#### restrict: `'E'` : directive name match element name

So directive look like this:

```
  <my-customer></my-customer>
```

#### scope: { customerInfo: '=info'}

```
  <my-customer info="myInfo"></my-customer>
```

this will bind `myInfo` to scope just like this expression:

```
  $scope.customerInfo = myInfo;
```

this is a concrete sample of how to read data from its element and modify the controller's scope.

Comment: Yeah, I've read that, but none of the examples cover what I'm trying to do, and I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: Do you have a concrete sample of how I'd write a directive that *reads* data from its element and modifies the controller's scope?

Comment: Hmm, okay, so the `scope` is what I need to be looking at? I'll have a closer look tomorrow again, thanks for now.

Comment: Sorry, still getting nowhere with this. What I need is something that, for every `ng-item` directive, get all nested `ng-category` directives/elements and do something like `$scope.categories.push({ name : category })`. I can't see how I can get this done with a simple `scope` definition. I'm trying to have a callback function invoked once for each directive, that's all. Or maybe I'm not thinking angular enough yet for this task. A concrete implementation would really help.